# Split dataframe into two using Data as splitting point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe which has 100,000 rows and 24 columns; representing crime over a year period October 2019 - October 2020

I'm trying to split the my df into two one dataframe of all rows ranging from october 1st - 31st March and the second ranging from April 1st - October 31st;

Would anyone be able to kindly assist how using pandas?

Comment: can you share the sample data? how the dataframe looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column is of datetime type. You can do like this :

```
import pandas as pd
split_data = pd.datetime(2020,03,31)

df_1 = df.loc[df['Date']<= split_date]
df_2 = df.loc[df['Date'] > split_date]
```

if the column containing date field is not datetime type. You should first convert it into datetime type.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```